# webView loads in simulator but not on the device

Tags: iphone

The following line works in the device and simulator just fine:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myURLgoesHere.com"]]];
```

The following lines (in various versions) works fine in the simulator, but won't load the page in the device.  Any Suggestions?

```
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[SharedClass sharedSharedClass].myURL]; // myURL is a NSString in my shared class
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tempURL]];
```

Why would this quit working when I go from a hardcoded string to my shared string?  The shared string works fine in other views and even gets stored to a plist file just fine.

Comment: If you step through with the debugger, what is the value of tempURL right before the second line?

Comment: Andrew, it appeared to be correct, but I think it may have had a space in it or something... not sure, I deleted the URL and retyped it, trying not to fat finger and it worked fine... my second option was to copy paste, I guess I need to add some indication to this so if it isn't loading it tells the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know as soon as I post this it started working...  must have been something funny with the URL like a space or ????